# Node access to anonymous user

Tags: users

Is there any way to make some nodes accessible to anonymous users in drupal and rest of the nodes content accessible to only authenticated users . I have a site which offers questions for practice . I want to keep some nodes(questions) accessible to anonymous users to see a sample before they can decide to be a premium user . 
Any pointers on this is highly appreciated .

Regards 
Meenakshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Content Access module [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)

```
   This will allows you to manage permissions for content types by role and author.this will allow you to manage permission for node that you want to access to anomyous and authenticated users.
```